# Backuppc not backing up Windows servers

Tags: backuppc

A few days ago, I posted an issue pertaining to backups not running on schedule. 
The problem was identified and resolved by increasing the 
WakeUpSchedule and MaxBackup settings. 
for 2 days, the backups worked without any problems. 
This morning, I opened the WGUI and all of the Windows servers had the message 'backup failed (tar:712 Total bytes received: 0 or some number)
I can manually start and complete any Linux machine but any Windows machine indicates it starts and then 
fails. 
The XFerLOG.bad has this little bit of info... 
Xfer PIDs are now 56244,56243 
tar:1236 Getting files newer than Mon Apr 18 19:00:01 2016 
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated

Any suggestions? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue after a bunch of system updates. I fixed this by following the instructions here; https://bugzilla.redhat.com/attachment.cgi?id=1111264&action=diff
i.e. edit:

```
/usr/share/backuppc/lib/BackupPC/CGI/Browse.pm
```

change

```
if ( !defined($In{num}) && defined(@Backups) && @Backups > 0 ) {
```

to

```
if ( !defined($In{num}) && @Backups > 0 ) {
```

edit:

```
/usr/share/backuppc/lib/BackupPC/Xfer/Smb.pm
```

change

```
} elsif ( /^\s*tar: dumped \d+ files/ ) {
```

to

```
} elsif ( /^\s*tar: dumped \d+ files/
                || /Total bytes received: \d+/i
          ) {
```

and insert

```
|| /^tar:\d+/
```

between

```
} elsif ( /smb: \\>/
```

and

```
|| /^\s*added interface/i
```

to make

```
} elsif ( /smb: \\>/
|| /^tar:\d+/
|| /^\s*added interface/i
```

Now I'm getting errors in the logs that certain file and pathnames can't be converted to UTF-8 which I never had before.. but the backups are working at least.